# Why am I receiving random characters in uart?

Tags: c, stm32, uart, freertos, stm32cubeide

I am editing the question to make it clear.

So I have a  naze32 rev6 board, I am trying to write custom firmware to the board. I am currently testing UART purpose being when I write drivers for sensors I can use UART to send the sensor data to PC via serial communication.

```
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  uint8_t Message[] = "Hello, World!!";
  for(;;)
  {
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Message, sizeof(Message), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}

static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzB1J.png)

I am attaching the screenshot of my putty settings.

this is what i receive.

> `|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒`|▒*▒▒*R▒

Note -

If I use below LL firmware the serial port works fine.

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

int main (void)
{

    RCC->APB2ENR |= (RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN | RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN);
    
    GPIOA->CRH |= (GPIO_CRH_MODE9 | GPIO_CRH_CNF9_1);
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_CNF9_0);
    
    USART1->BRR = 0x1D4C;
    USART1->CR1 |= (USART_CR1_UE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE);
    
    for(;;)
    {
        if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE)
        {
            char temp = USART1->DR;
            USART1->DR = temp;
            while(!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TC));
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B12dX.png)

Comment: Maybe you have some wrong serial settings on the PC? baud rate, data bits. flow control, etc. Have you checked that?

Comment: It's not obvious what settings you have on the sending side either. Try going with 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit - on both sides.

Comment: There is no UART initialization in your source as posted. How do you know the communication parameters on the PC side?

Comment: The string you receive is about twice longer than what you transmit. This could signify that the receiving end has double baudrate. Has pointed out before, check baud rates  and other settings.

Comment: BTW HAL_UART_Transmit in task - horrible. It will block other tats until this one is done.

Comment: For sure wrong settings

Comment: huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

baudrate - 115200
Stop bit = 1
Parity = none
Data bits = 8

Note I tried with both full & half duplex.
this code just uses Half duplex trnasmit only.

Comment: @VarunKoganti [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69039782/edit) your question to add the missing code. Make sure it's a [mre]. I see that you have set it up to `8n1 @ 115200`. Is that how the receiving side is set up to?

Comment: Yes 8 data no parity 1 stop bit, baud rate at 115200, intried only UART with superloop and it is still not working. I will edit the question.

Comment: The other cases I see this with is when you are running at a MCU clock rate that isn't sufficient to keep up with load. I don't have a  naze32 board, but if you can set the clock-rate higher (e.g. running at 3MHz, try setting at 6MHz or 12MHz).

Comment: @Mr. David C, my board is running with 8 mHz external crystal PLL set to 72MHz. The chip is essentially an stm32 f103cbt6 connected to cp2104 via UART1.

Comment: Get an oscilloscope and measure the line to find out on which side the error is, the sender or the receiver.